# jQuery not working in head but OK in body

Tags: jquery

If I place my jQuery at the end of the body without $(document).ready(function() , it works fine. If I place it in the head using $(document).ready(function(), it no longer works. I realized I needed the function() when placing jQuery in the head from here, but when I try to implement it myself, no dice. I've stared at it too long, I'm not seeing the problem.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#testTable tr").hover(
            function(){$(this).addClass("highlighted");},
            function(){$(this).removeClass("highlighted");} 
        );
});
</script>

<style type='text/css'>
.tablerow {background-color:yellow;}
.tableheader {background-color:Pink;}
.highlighted {background-color:Green;}
</style>    
</head>

<body>
<table id="testTable">
    <thead class="tableheader">
        <tr><th>No</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Salary</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="testBody">
        <tr class="tablerow"><td>1</td><td>Yong Mook Kim</td><td>28</td><td>$100,000</td></tr>
        <tr class="tablerow"><td>2</td><td>Low Yin Fong</td><td>29</td><td>$90,000</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: That exact HTML seems to work for me

Comment: what's "not working"? what kind of errors do you get?

Comment: I assume you have `<html></html>` tags in your markup?

Comment: It is working for me. Like @kennypu said, check your javascript console for errors. As an aside, you can simplify by using `$(function(){...});` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: Just to be sure open your browser console and see if jQuery is really being loaded; and add console.log($) right before $(document).ready() also.

Comment: And you probably want to change your selector to $("#testBody tr"), so only the body's tr get highlighted.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. What wasn't working for me (which I should have stated, as apparent by my question being closed, I blame it on my newness) was the highlighting on hover. VisioN - yes, had the html. BryanH - thanks for the javascript console tip. @Romimer - thanks for the log tip. Since it worked for others, at least that told me I wasn't missing anything. I had about 20 other jquery add-ons in the head, that if I removed, the hover function worked. So that points me in the right direction. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try referencing the css document before the script , here is the documentation http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: There's no CSS document referenced in his code. And even if there were, it would be loaded by the time `.ready()` runs, so the order shouldn't matter.

Comment: I meant put up the style tags before the script tag  , from the documentation : "When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the scripts."

Comment: That sentence is explaining _why_ you should use the `.ready()` handler -- it ensures that you meet that requirement.

Comment: That's what I thought too at one point, but it didn't seem to matter, and I also thought the .ready was suppose to make that irrelevant. Thanks.